# reversing a string using a stack

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I am trying to reverse a string using a stack but I get a segmentation error in the second while loop , can't say why :

```
void ReverseString (char *s)
{
    stack <char> temp;

    char *q = s;
    cout<<"Test1: "<<q<<endl;
    while(*q != NULL)
    {
        cout<<*q<<endl;
        temp.push(*q);
        q++;

    }
    q=s;

    while(temp.size() !=0)
    {

        *q=temp.top();

        temp.pop();
        q++;    
    }


}
```

Comment: Your example is incomplete. The calling code is missing. If it is `ReverseString(NULL)`, for example, your code will crash.

Comment: Would you try to reverse a litteral array?

Comment: ok but still the error i get is at :
*q=temp.top();

Comment: what's wrong with that assuming that i am not reversing a null string

Comment: @DanielDaranas why should it Crash?

Comment: Show us the calling site. I've got an answer ready but I want to be sure.

Comment: can you show how you call the function?

Comment: btw, I'd recommend to use `while(!temp.empty())` instead of `while(temp.size() !=0)`

Comment: @TomasDittmann `char *q = s;`, `while(*q != NULL)` will be undefined if `s` is NULL. Clearly `q` will be NULL, too (it is `s`!), so `*q` will be illegal.

Comment: @DanielDaranas Ah correct! I did not see that dereferencing. Thanks!

Comment: Don't compare characters to `NULL`. Use `0` or, possibly, `'\0'`. You should only use `NULL` for comparing pointers, but since this is 2016 you shouldn't use it at all, you should use `nullptr`.

Comment: Your compiler should have warned you. If it didn't, upgrade.

Comment: Where is your [MCVE]? You don't even show the calling code, let alone includes!

Comment: char *s = "test";

 ReverseString(s);

Comment: @M.Cesar: That is illegal code. You cannot initialise a `char*` from a string literal. And you certainly can't modify a string literal...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem comes in when trying to write to `q` : `*q=temp.top();`. A string literal is of the type `const char[]` which means that it'll get stored read only memory, attempting to overwrite it is undefined behaviour and a segmentation fault in this case. Really though, a good compiler should've already warned you about a cast from `const char*` to `char*`. You should copy it to a char array and edit that, something like:

```
char text[] = "Reversethis";
ReverseString(text);
```

Anyway, this is very C-like C++ and I would suggest to just use `std::string` with a `std::reverse(string.begin(), string.end())` call.

Comment: A good, modern compiler should've _banned_ the conversion from `const char*` to `char*`.

Comment: @lightnessRacesinOrbit Not if OP isn't compiling for C++11 or higher :^)

Comment: _"A good, modern compiler"_ I do not consider modern compilers running in non-modern modes to be in this category ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit C++ is timeless

Comment: No, `<chrono>` was added in C++11

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Checkmate, you got me.